# Questions on CAN bit stuffing

Tags: automotive, can

I am new to the CAN. I have came across bit stuffing which is used to ensure that all receivers nodes are synchronized to transmitter node (After 5 bits of the same polarity, CAN will add a bit stuffing bit of the opposite polarity).

I have some doubts regarding bit stuffing in CAN:

> Bit stuffing in not applied to Identifier field in CAN protocol.

1. Is this statement correct?

> All bits after Identifier field will be bit stuffed if applicable

2. Is this statement also correct?

Comment: The source for those - as I don’t think they are original...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first statement is wrong - the identifier field must be bit stuffed. The CAN bus uses the stuff bit for two purposes: to synchronise timing between nodes, and to signal an active error condition. If the identifier field is not stuffed, then it would not have either of these capabilities.

Comment: Thanks Jon for correcting me. I am confused with arbitration when there bit stuffing is involved. Let us assume that Node A and B tries to transmit data frame simultaneously. Node A transmits frame with identifier 10000010001 and Node B with identifier 11010001001. Which node will succeed in transmitting? How will arbitration work in this case?

Comment: @cdev Arbitration happens on a bit by bit basis. If you get to the point of a stuff bit being sent, then all bits beforehand must have been identical (no arbitration) so the stuff bit will also be identifical. Once a different bit is detected one node immediately stops transmitting and any differences in stuff bits doesn't matter any more.

Answer (score 0):

From the CAN Spec:

> The ERROR FLAG’s form violates the law of bit stuffing (see
>   CODING) applied to all fields from START OF FRAME to CRC DELIMITER or destroys
>   the fixed form ACK FIELD or END OF FRAME field.

which includes the identifier.